# something went wrong when I try add a layer on a matrix of data (python)

Tags: python, matrix

So assume I have a matrix here, a tuple containing tuples of 0:

```
matrix = ((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
          (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),)
```

I want to add a layer of int(1) on the outside of it, so that it will look like:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],]
```

first of all, I want to turn this matrix to list, since tuples are not changable:

```
matrix_new = list(map(lambda x: list(x), matrix))
```

Then I would like to add a row at the beginning and end of it.

```
addrow = list(map(lambda x: 1, range(len(matrix[0]))))
matrix_new.insert(0, addrow)
matrix_new.append(addrow)
```

so now, if I:

```
for i in matrix_new:
    print(i)
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

looking good so far.
Now I want to add a int(1) in each row of the matrix_new at the beginning and the end:

```
for i in matrix_new:
    i.insert(0, 1)
    i.append(1)
    print(i)
```

somehow it now looks like:

```
>>>    
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

It seems that the last row is having 2 additional int(1)??????
And now, if I:

```
for i in matrix_new:
    print(i)
```

I got:

```
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now I got the first row also with 2 additional int(1).

What could be wrong? I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: list(x), matrix))` ==> `list(map(list, matrix))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first and last rows of ones you are appending to the matrix are in fact aliases for the same list, therefore you are appending twice to it. You need to modify your code, maybe like this:

```
addrow1 = list(map(lambda x: 1, range(len(matrix[0]))))
addrow2 = list(map(lambda x: 1, range(len(matrix[0]))))
matrix_new.insert(0, addrow1)
matrix_new.append(addrow2)
```

Comment: After realizing my mistake, I think I can take use of `itertool.tee()` for this:
`addrow1, addrow2 = itertools.tee(list(map(lambda x: 'x', range(len(matrix[0])))))`
 `matrix_new.insert(0, list(addrow1))`
 `matrix_new.append(list(addrow2))`